# What is the meaning of a dot (.) after an integer in c?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I would like to know if anybody knew what a . after an integer in C means.

i have this piece of code i want to convert and that is the only thing i am not sure of what it does.

if (y>=0.)
what does the . here do?

full code:

```
double angleOf(double x, double y) {

  double  dist=sqrt(x*x+y*y) ;

  if (y>=0.) return acos( x/dist);
  else       return acos(-x/dist)+.5*CIRCLE_RADIANS; }
```

Comment: y is a double... It is not an integer.

Comment: as i saw it: the . is after the zero(0) so after an integer

Comment: (by the way) you can omit the leading `0` as well: `.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's same as `0.0`, it will treat it as double instead of an integer, so you don't need to cast it.

Comment: thanks so much for the aswer :D i feel like such a beginner asking such dumb questions.

Answer (score 3):

The trailing dot makes the literal a floating point (double) literal, instead of an integer one.